# How to have a Function App tell a Logic App that it failed

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App invoking a Function App. The Function App may fail, and if it does, I want the Logic App to do it's retry thing. But I don't know what is the correct way of conveying failure back to the Logic App. My Function App signature is

```
public static async Task Run(...)
```

Is throwing an exception the only option? I assume there's a better way, as I want to Logic App to get back my out params even if the Function App fails.

Answer (score 1):

The logic app calls your function app via webhook, so by throwing an exception you send an error http response back to logic apps.

You could, upon detecting an error in the function, create and return an error response yourself. Here's some documentation on logic app error handling, it might have info on the parameter handling you're hoping for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling

Comment: Just echoing this - if the Azure Function returns some Error response (Bad Request, 4xx whatever) the Logic App wil lknow it failed, get the context returned from the function, and continue on with the workflow (either fail, call some compensating actions, etc.)

Comment: Apologies - I didn't ask the right question. This particular function is triggered directly and not by a Logic App. In that light, how does one control the "retry on failure" logic? Or is that not possible with Function Apps?

Comment: If you want retry on failure through functions, the best option is to use a queue triggered function, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#handling-poison-queue-messages

Comment: My function is currently blob triggered. Would I have to change it to queue triggered in order to get automatic retry capability?

Comment: Nope, blobs have similar retry behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#handling-poison-blobs